# NSBezierPath added unwanted inverted rectangle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uibezierpath, nsbezierpath

I have a custom NSView linked up with a custom view in my xib.

1. **code from the view:**

   ```
   @implementation GDStatusPopoverActivateButton
   - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
       NSBezierPath* path = [GDAssets getPathForTimesIconWithRect: self.bounds];
       NSAffineTransform* transformer = [[NSAffineTransform alloc] init];
       [transformer scaleBy: 0.25];
       [path transformUsingAffineTransform: transformer];
       [[NSColor blackColor] setFill];
       [path fill];
       [super drawRect: dirtyRect];
   }
   @end
   ```
2. **path code** (GDAssets getPathForTimesIconWithRect call).

   ```
   + (NSBezierPath *) getPathForTimesIconWithRect: (NSRect) rect {
       NSBezierPath* timesPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: rect];
       [timesPath moveToPoint: NSMakePoint(128, 240.48)];
       [timesPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(15.52, 128) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(65.88, 240.48) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(15.52, 190.12)];
       [timesPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(128, 15.51) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(15.52, 65.88) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(65.88, 15.51)];
       [timesPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(240.48, 128) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(190.12, 15.51) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(240.48, 65.88)];
       [timesPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(128, 240.48) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(240.48, 190.12) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(190.12, 240.48)];
       [timesPath closePath];
       [timesPath moveToPoint: NSMakePoint(256, 128)];
       [timesPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(128, 0) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(256, 57.31) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(198.69, 0)];
       [timesPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(0, 128) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(57.31, 0) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(0, 57.31)];
       [timesPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(128, 256) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(0, 198.69) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(57.31, 256)];
       [timesPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(256, 128) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(198.69, 256) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(256, 198.69)];
       [timesPath closePath];
       return timesPath;
   }
   ```
3. **xib:**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xGeC1yO.png]

**result:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPDPA.png]

Answer (score 0):

this line was the culprit

```
NSBezierPath* timesPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: rect];
```

solution:

```
NSBezierPath* timesPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
```